# Coastline fractal proportions

Tags: java, fractals

I'm making a coastline fractal on a window that is one by one wide, and I would like to make the very first one pictured below, however, I cannot figure out which x and y coordinates to use to make the angles form 90 degrees and still fit on the screen, I don't need any code, I just would like how to figure out which x and y coordinates to use. Thanks!

[image: Coastline Fractal]

Points:
1st point: (0,0.5)
2nd point: (0.25,0.75)
3rd point: (0.75,0)
4th point: (1,0.5)

My work (although messy and illegible at times): [image]

---

It looks like from the picture that the first and last point both have a y-value of 0.5. Since the viewing window is one, you divide it into 4 parts each of which is 0.25 in length. The triangles that are formed if you draw a horizontal line at y=0.5 are isosceles according to the image. Thus, you solve: sin(45)=x/0.5.

Comment: This looks to be a job for recursion. What graphics library are you using? Swing? AWT? SWT? This will have bearing on answers. If Swing, consider using the dimensions of the component or BufferedImage that the drawing is occurring in, and base your x and y on that.

Comment: As for the angles, that's nothing more than trigonometry. I'd work on solving it on paper first before trying to commit code where given any two points, I could would figure out the angles and line segments. Where are you stuck on this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am using both AWT and Swing, and the window is 1 by 1. I just figured out the optimal x and y cordinates which I will post below.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I used trig, but unsucessfully

Comment: ??`... and the window is 1 by 1`?? what do you mean by this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels x and y coordinates are doubles in between 0 and 1

Comment: and regarding `"I used trig, but unsucessfully..."` Please show us.

Answer (score 0):

re `"x and y coordinates are doubles in between 0 and 1"`,

Then you will need to translate from your model (the set of points that make up your fractal) and the view (the GUI display). The model will go from 0 to 1, the view from 0 to the graphical window's width. A simple linear transformation where you multiply the model by some scale factor will serve.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're wanting to map an abstract coordinate system to your screen.

Let's say your endpoints (in arbitrary coordinates) are (0, 0) and (1, 0).  Then your points for the leftmost figure, in this system, will be (0, 0), (1/4, sqrt(2)/4), (1/2, 0), (3/4, -sqrt(2)/4), and (1, 0).

The other diagrams are calculated by some method.  It sounded like your question was focusing on fitting it to the screen, so I'll continue with that.  The method for fitting it to the screen is the same.

From there, you have a screen coordinate system.  Each point is transformed to the screen.  Let's say you have a 1000 by 1000 screen, with screen coordinates (0, 0) in the upper left.  If you want to take up the entire screen, then you'd do the following:

- Flip the y coordinates (+y is down on your screen)
- Determine the full range in x and y for your arbitrary coordinates (1 for x, sqrt(2)/2 for y)
- Multiply x values by 1000, and y values by 2000 / sqrt(2) to expand to the screen.
- Subtract 500 from y values to center the image in the y direction.